# How many threads can a Java VM support on post-2012 hardware

Tags: java

I know this has been asked before, but a few years ago. (Answer was a 'few thousand' in 2009.) I'm wondering what the current answer would be now hardware has become considerably faster.

I'm embarking on a new project and the design choices I make depend on the current answers, not previous ones.

Many thanks.

More details (following EJP request for clarification):

I'll be able to procure a 64 bit server with 4GB RAM. The only thing running on the server (other than Windows of course) will be this JVM so presumably I can allocate most of the memory to the heap no? Let's say 4 CPUs and 4 cores in each. My intuition says no more than 1000 threads but I can't justify that.

Comment: I would make that a configuration option in your application so that you can adjust it to different hardware.

Comment: Current answers for what? Operating system? RAM? Hard disk? Number of CPUs? Without all that and more your question amounts to 'how long is a piece of string?' NB the answer was a lot more than a few thousand in 2009.

Comment: Current answer meaning "how many threads". The machine would be a reasonably-priced (yes a loose term I know but we can't spend megabucks on it) server running Windows. The answer in 2009 seems to be contradicted by t. heintz' reply so I'm still at a loss.

Comment: Current answer *for what hardware?* and all the other things I asked. Also how much heap allocated for JVM? 32-bit or 64-bit? There is no absolute limit on threads independent of these qualifications. Your question remains meaningless.

Comment: I'll be able to procure a 64 bit server with 4GB RAM. The only thing running on the server (other than Windows of course) will be this JVM so presumably I can allocate most of the memory to the heap no? Let's say 4 CPUs and 4 cores in each. My intuition says no more than 1000 threads but I can't justify that.

Comment: A *Server* with 4GB? Really? What I *can tell* you is that if you use about 1-1.5GB Heap with a 32-Bit Windows VM, you tend to run out of memory/address space (for the thread stacks) between 1K and 2K threads.

Answer (score -2):

As for your question, here is an uninformed guess: still a couple of thousand.

More importantly though: Regardless of hardware advances, its still not a smart idea to run thousands of concurrent threads. Maybe you should rethink your application design?

Answer (score -2):

Depends the size of your ram and the memory each thread is consuming . . .

in theory total Threads at a time will be= `total-memory/memory-used-by-one-thread`

but there will be other programs also running on your system. .

so we will have 'total-effective-memory-available/memory-used-by-one-thread'